# Android Service instead Thread

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application where I need to share a task between two `Activities`, this task should receive data from a connected host and *update* the activity when messages are available.
Up to now I did this trough a `Thread` right on the `Activity` and it is working fine.
Now I need to add more activities that need the same data but I would like to avoid duplicating code and I wish to do something in a more *structured* manner.
I started reading the Service guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) but I get confused. In my original idea I tought I need a *bound* service but after some reading I switched back on a *Started* service.
The original Thread service structure is this:

```
private class TelemetryReceiverThread extends Thread {
    private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 1500;
    private static final int UDP_SERVER_RESPAWN = 2000;

    private final int UDP_SERVER_PORT;
    private boolean keepRunning = true;
    private boolean paused = false;

    public TelemetryReceiverThread(int listen_port) {
        UDP_SERVER_PORT = listen_port;
    }

    public void run() {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];

        final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        DatagramSocket socket = null;

        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(UDP_SERVER_RESPAWN);
                socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(UDP_SERVER_PORT));

                while (keepRunning) {
                    socket.receive(packet);

                    final String message = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());

                    if (!paused)
                        telemetryTask(message);
                }

                socket.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (keepRunning);

        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    void play() {
        paused = false;
    }

    void pause() {
        paused = true;
    }

    void kill() {
        keepRunning = false;
    }
}
```

`telemetryTask` method is an activity method that decode message and updates the UI.

Switching to a `Service` structure I would like to dispatch the collected message to the `Activity` trough `Intent` and collected it trough a `BroadCastReceiver`. Right?

The example provided in the guide is confusing me and I have not been able to find a cleaner example of a `Service` housing a `Thread` to make asynchronous operations. Someone can help me with a more specific (and hopefully cleaner) reference?

A more general question: is my approach correct? There's a more **Android** *compliant* way to do what I need?

Comment: You're free to bind to a started service and get direct reference to it by passing service object trough a binder (if it runs in the same process which is usually the case)

Comment: @Pawel I know I can do this. The matter, for me of course, is, given my peculiar need, the Service should be started or bound? I know it sounds like philosophy ...

Comment: You can start the service to have it run continuously then bind to it while omitting `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag to prevent binding from affecting its lifecycle (won't create the service if its not started, won't prevent service from being destroyed when it's stopped).

Comment: so in the same `Activity` I have to start the service then bind to it.. right?

Comment: Yes just request start service in every activity that will bind to it (without `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag) and ignore start command inside service if it is already running.